# Sqlite - How to efficiently insert or update millions of rows?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, transactions

I have thousands of text files consisting of an item and the supplier code that are in the following format:

```
item_name,supplier_code
```

So for example:

```
Potatoes,10294
Rope,49013
Beans,23958
Soap,12495
```

I want to add them to a single table in sqlite with just 2 columns, one for the item name and the other for the list of suppliers where each unique supplier is seperated by a comma. So for example it can look something like this:

```
Beans|23958,23467,35994
```

Each item can only occur once in the table and the second column can only have unique supplier codes - so if a text file had Beans,23958, which was also in another text file that was previously processed then this line would not get added to the table as both the item name and supplier code already exist.

As I have this data in thousands of text files, which will ultimilately lead to hundreds of thousands of rows (if not millions), how can I efficiently add each item but ensuring that the item is only added once and any subsequent additions of the item are merely just appending the supplier code column (without adding duplicate supplier codes)? I have thought about running 2 queries, the first checking if an item name exists in the table - if it does then just update the supplier code by appending the new code if it too doesnt exist. If the item name doesnt exist then just simply running a basic insert query with the item name and supplier.

This way seems like it will not be efficient with the sheer number of lines I will be processing. I have looked at using transactions but not sure how this will work as if a transaction isnt committed then we will not know whether an insert or an update is needed.

I would appreciate any ideas or logic or even suggestions to look at alternative storage methods.

Comment: use this SQL statement like `INSERT OR REPLACE`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, SQLite is not a good choice for large amounts of data, like you have.

You better use MySQL, PostgreSQL, or some NoSQL alternative.

And after choosing a right solution, I think you need to import this data into the intermediate table. In PostgreSQL, for example, that will look like:

Create your table:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier_codes
(item_name char(250), supplier_code integer);
```

Copy data from your CSV files to the table:

```
COPY supplier_codes FROM '/path/to/csv/supplier_code.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

After that, you can make queries and transform the data as you need:

```
SELECT item_name, string_agg(supplier_code, ', ')
FROM supplier_codes
GROUP BY item_name;
```

Comment: One of the reasons for doing this is to reduce storage size as having many text files with duplicate data will just take up unecessary space. Also another reason is to make searching for this data quick and efficient. With that in mind, simply importing the csv files into the database and then running select query to group the data is not efficient as the table will have all sorts of duplicate data.

Comment: I see, but anyway I think you need to do some intermediate queries and steps before the final results. 
For example, you can create another table and populate it with the results of the group query. After that, you can go over the table and update it removing duplicates from the supplier_code string. 

Btw, with SQLite, you will not reach quick and efficient search. Also if you want  to be able to search by supplier_code in SQL, not just item_name, you better store it in original format 1 item - 1 code.

Comment: More of that, you can create multicolumn unique constraints and prevent populating your table with duplicates